# Custom image while dragging an CWnd-derived object

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, drag-and-drop, cwnd

I want to display a custom image while dragging an object in a drag&drop operation.

I have created a CWnd-derived control (a chart) and I display 4 of them in the same dialog. I've implemented drag&drop using COleDataSource so that the user can change its position by dragging and dropping the control. Now I would like to display a small version of the same chart is been dragging instead of the typical cursor.

Is there an "easy" way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were not many answers!

I managed to do it using templates (to allow any CWnd-derived control to use the functionality) and CImageList (to display the dragged image).

I can't post source code here because it's a commercial application but if somebody it's trying to do something similar and needs my help. I'll try to help him/her out.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a cool solution.

Please accept your answer so the question is marked as answered.

Comment: here looking to do the same...  is it available?